# Facebook ad optimized for post engagement but charges for impressions

Tags: advertising, facebook, impressions

We have a Facebook ad running under a "post engagement" campaign and have set the "ad optimized for" option to "post engagement".

We get two options for "what you get charged for": impressions, and post engagement.

The bid shows as "X value" per post engagement.

How does Facebook charge for "impressions" (if we keep the default option selected to pay for impressions)? Wouldn't it only be valid to charge for "post engagement" given our ad optimization setting?

Answer (score 1):

Under Facebook's optimize for post engagement option the pricing section should have said

> Your bid will be optimized to get more engagement on your page post. You'll be charged each time your advert is served.

Additionally below that section there is a choice between getting the most engagement for your post at the best price which states that it will be charged for impressions, and setting the amount that a post engagement is worth to you.

By Facebook's definition engagement means whenever someone clicks, likes, comments, or shares your post. If you left the default radio button selected then you would be charged for both engagement as well as impressions.

https://www.facebook.com/business/learn/facebook-create-ad-page-post-engagement
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/614797551881954